# Find unique first and last name combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns First Name and Last Name. The table contain duplicate entries by swap of first and last name for some records.

E.g.,

```
First Name Last name
--------------------
john       Keats 
Ray        Owano
Keats      john
Joseph     taylor
Owano      Ray
```

I want to find the unique combination of first name and last name.

I tried to create a flag with all 1s and tried doing a full outer join to get all possible combinations and tried to filter unique combinations but it did not help and I got struck.

Comment: so in that case (based on inputs given) you want to return --> joshep taylor! right?

Comment: from what i understand, 'john keats' and 'keats john' are duplicate in your opinion. is it true ?

Comment: @Doruk yes it is duplicate since name is same

Comment: @ReturnZero - no It should remove duplicate records except one hence the output should be only 3 records after removing duplicates

Answer (score 2):

One option is to do a distinct select on the smaller and larger of the first and last name, across your entire table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN first < last THEN first ELSE last END AS first,
    CASE WHEN first < last THEN last ELSE first END AS last
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that I am arbitrarily reporting the lowest name first.  Since a given first/last pair can be in any direction, which name we report as "first" is therefore arbitrary.

Comment: How does first < last work? Is this basis count of characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can try also like following using a `self join`.

```
SELECT T1.firstname, 
       T1.lastname 
FROM   [TableName] T1 
       LEFT JOIN [TableName] T2 
              ON T1.firstname = T2.lastname 
                 AND T1.lastname = T2.firstname 
                 AND T1.firstname > T2.firstname 
WHERE  T2.lastname IS NULL 
GROUP  BY T1.firstname, 
          T1.lastname
```

**Note:** Remove `GROUP BY` if you want to show duplicate records also.

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/GMEV88249)

**Output**

```
+-----------+----------+
| FirstName | LastName |
+-----------+----------+
| john      | Keats    |
+-----------+----------+
| Joseph    | taylor   |
+-----------+----------+
| Owano     | Ray      |
+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can concatenate firstname with lastname, and check whether the name combination exists or not:

```
  Select FirstName, LastName From dbo.table Where (FirstName+LastName) not in (Select LastName+FirstName From dbo.table);
```

it will return 'Joshep Taylor' which is unique!